# Using Spring annotations, how can we use DI with a superclass via annotations?

Tags: spring, annotations

I have the following class defined as a bean:

```
@Repository("userDao")
public class UserDao extends JdoDaoSupport implements IUserDao {...}
```

The class JdoDaoSupport requires a `persistenceManagerFactory` injected into it.

I've declared the persistenceManagerFactory bean in XML, how do I inject it to my superclass using annotations?

JdoDaoSupport class (snipped):

```
public abstract class JdoDaoSupport extends DaoSupport {
   public final void setPersistenceManagerFactory
                           (PersistenceManagerFactory persistenceManagerFactory) {
   this.jdoTemplate = createJdoTemplate(persistenceManagerFactory);
}
```

Comment: I found the same question here with a less than enthralling answer: http://efreedom.com/Question/1-3807707/Injecting-Derived-Property-Repository-Bean-Without-Autowired-Super-Class

Comment: possible duplicate of [injecting derived property for @Repository bean without @Autowired in super class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3807707/injecting-derived-property-for-repository-bean-without-autowired-in-super-class)

Comment: I think that question covers the options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally came across a good recommendation. It is to not use JdoDaoSupport, this is only  used in cases when it's absolutely necessary (as it ties your class to the spring framework). Instead just dependency inject the PersistenceManagerFactory into your class, thus negating the benefit of extending JdoDaoSupport.